# Calling VueJS Components after login from an external script

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, methods, callback

I have a VueJS Program where I want to provide a login. Thus this login is used one multiple platforms, it is loaded via an external server (See: mounted). It is loaded, puts elements into the mainlogin-div creating a login view and when the user clicks Login it performs a http login request to another server. When the login is successful, the external script calls done(result) or error(result) whether the login was a success or not.

But now of course how can I go back to calling Vue-stuff from there? I cant just do like this.$router.push("/coolPath") or call a defined method like loggedIn to make a toast or what not... How is this implemented?

```
<template>
  <div id="main">

    <div id="mainlogin"></div>

    <script type="application/javascript">
      function done(result){
        console.log(result);

        loggedIn(result, true)
      }
      function error(result) {
        console.log(result)

        loggedIn(result, false)
      }

    </script>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
const Toast = require("@/toast/toast")

export default {
  name: "Login",
  components: {},

  data() {
    return {
      isAuthenticated: false
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    let loginScript = document.createElement('script')
    loginScript .setAttribute('src', 'http://**.***.***.***/index_krass.js')
    document.body.appendChild(loginScript )
  },
  methods: {
    loggedIn: function (result, success){
      Toast.toast(result.message, success)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
...
</style>
```

Error is always "this." is not defined or loggedIn(...) is not defined...
Maybe its some race condition where VueJS needs to be loaded first or the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `<script>` block in the template, just set the global functions up on `window` as [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to capture the Vue instance context:

```js
export default {
  beforeMount() {
    window.done = result => this.loggedIn(result, true)
    window.error = result => this.loggedIn(result, false)
 
    let loginScript = document.createElement("script")
    loginScript.setAttribute("src", ".../index_krass.js")
    document.body.appendChild(loginScript)
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.done = window.error = undefined
  },
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-vue-instance-to-external-script-khlwg?file=/src/components/Login.vue:257-456)